# In a Delphi thread's, when the memory is freed?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7

A thread has assigned

```
FreeOnTerminate := true;
```

I understand that it's memory wil be freed when it terminates, but when does the *Terminate* event will happen?

Or, in a more generic way, when is the memory related to some thread freed?

Comment: There is no `Terminate` event. All you need to know can be found in the procedure named `ThreadProc` function which can be found in `Classes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `FreeOnTerminate` is true, `TThread` frees its own memory (calls its own destructor on itself) after `TThread.DoTerminate()` has been called and exited, after `TThread.Execute()` has been called and exited.  So basically, once `DoTerminate()` has been called (which internally triggers the `TThread.OnTerminate` event, if assigned) and exited, assume your `TThread` object is no longer valid if `FreeOnTerminate` is true.

Answer (score 8):

The memory for the thread itself is freed when the thread is freed (IOW, when it's destructor exits). `FreeOnTerminate` just means that when the thread has been terminated (the `Execute` method exits) the destructor will be called automatically.

Any memory the thread allocates for its own use should be freed by the thread in its destructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: AFAIR, TThread.Terminate is a flag property (which the execute method can ignore or obey) indicating that the thread must finish its' work **NOW**.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That the `FTerminated` (IIRC) flag has been set by a call to `TThread.Terminate`. And Ken: that "or" should be an "and". Or actually the whole terminate thing can be removed there. The terminate flag can be ignored by the execute method and the execute method can terminate without a call to Terminate.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Since the `Execute` can be exited without the flag being set, isn't the `or` more appropriate (either the `Terminate` flag is set and `Execute` checks it and exits, *OR* the `Execute` function finishes without `Terminate` being set)? (On second thought, `Terminate` by itself does nothing if `Execute` doesn't check for it, so you're right. I'll edit. Thanks.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "Terminate has been set" has the typical meaning of what a Boolean flag having been set would mean: the value has been set to `True`. (I've edited out that sentence, as Marjan correctly identified it as being unnecessary to the answer.)

Comment: Terminate is a method and is not a boolean flag

Comment: @David: OK. As usual, whatever. It sets the `Terminated` boolean flag that tells the thread it's been terminated, meaning it **acts to set a Boolean flag**, and serves the same purpose. Do you need a documentation link to confirm that?

Comment: I didn't understand what you originally wrote, because your original post had a transcription error. You wrote `Terminate` when you meant `Terminated`. The response I was expecting from you was "Oh, I'm sorry, I made a little mistake, I will fix it."

Comment: Yuo're right. I mistook your comment as something else entirely; that was a little thin-skinned on my part. My apologies. (That portion has been removed from the answer, or I'd clarify it.) Once again, my apologies.